# tf.concat operation in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

`torch.stack` is not what I am searching.

I am looking for the Tensorflow's concat operation for Pytorch.

I have searched the doc http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive `torch.cat` is what you are looking for.

http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.cat